# Filtragem por datas - Verificação de meses 31 e fevereiro

Tags: c#, datetime

Possuo o seguinte código:

**Código exemplo, deve-se debugar e acompanhar a váriavel "lstItem" para entender o seu funcionamento**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TesteRotina
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Item> lstItem = new List<Item>
            {
                new Item
                {
                    IdItem = 1,
                    NomeModificador = "ITEM 1",
                    DataUltimaMontagem = new DateTime(2015, 10, 18),
                    DiaMontagem = 18,
                    TipoPeriodicidade = (int) TipoPeriodicidadeEnum.Mensal
                },
                new Item
                {
                    IdItem = 2,
                    NomeModificador = "ITEM 2",
                    DataUltimaMontagem = new DateTime(2015, 10, 31),
                    DiaMontagem = 31,
                    TipoPeriodicidade = (int) TipoPeriodicidadeEnum.Mensal
                },
                new Item
                {
                    IdItem = 3,
                    NomeModificador = "ITEM 3",
                    DataUltimaMontagem = new DateTime(2015, 10, 29),
                    DiaMontagem = 29,
                    TipoPeriodicidade = (int) TipoPeriodicidadeEnum.Mensal
                }
            };

            lstItem = FiltrarListaItem(lstItem);

        }

        private static List<Item> FiltrarListaItem(List<Item> lstItem)
        {
            List<Item> lstRetorno = new List<Item>();
            foreach (var item in lstItem)
            {
                var dataUltimaMontagem = item.DataUltimaMontagem;
                var diaMontagem = item.DiaMontagem;
                var tipoPeriodicidade = item.TipoPeriodicidade;

                switch (tipoPeriodicidade)
                {
                    case (int)TipoPeriodicidadeEnum.Mensal:
                        dataUltimaMontagem = dataUltimaMontagem.AddMonths(1);
                        break;
                    case (int)TipoPeriodicidadeEnum.Bimestral:
                        dataUltimaMontagem = dataUltimaMontagem.AddMonths(2);
                        break;
                    case (int)TipoPeriodicidadeEnum.Trimestral:
                        dataUltimaMontagem = dataUltimaMontagem.AddMonths(3);
                        break;
                    case (int)TipoPeriodicidadeEnum.Semestral:
                        dataUltimaMontagem = dataUltimaMontagem.AddMonths(6);
                        break;
                    case (int)TipoPeriodicidadeEnum.Anual:
                        dataUltimaMontagem = dataUltimaMontagem.AddYears(1);
                        break;
                }

                if (dataUltimaMontagem.Day.Equals(DateTime.Now.Day) && dataUltimaMontagem.Month.Equals(DateTime.Now.Month))
                    lstRetorno.Add(item);
            }

            return lstItem;
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public int IdItem { get; set; }
        public string NomeModificador { get; set; }
        public int TipoPeriodicidade { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataUltimaMontagem { get; set; }
        public int DiaMontagem { get; set; }
    }

    public enum TipoPeriodicidadeEnum
    {
        [Description("Mensal")]
        Mensal = 1,
        [Description("Bimestral")]
        Bimestral = 2,
        [Description("Trimestral")]
        Trimestral = 3,
        [Description("Semestral")]
        Semestral = 4,
        [Description("Anual")]
        Anual = 5
    }
}
```

No exemplo, o método `FiltrarListaItem`, retira todos os itens, que possuem `DataMontagem + periodiciodade > DataAtual`. 
Ex.:

> DataMontagem = 19/10/2015 e Periodicidade = Mensal. 
>   DataMontagem + Periodicidade = 19/11/2015. Este item seria
>   desconsiderado pois o resultado é maior que a DataAtual(18/11/2015).

Esta é uma rotina que ira ser executada todos os dias do ano.

Como eu faço para que Itens com o Dia da Montagem maior do que o ultimo dia do mês sejam considerados e passem pelo filtro? 
Ex.:

> DiaMontagem = 31 e o mês só vai até dia 30.
>  DiaMontagem = 29, 30
>   ou 31 e o mês só vai até 28, como é o caso de fevereiro.

Comment: O exemplo não funciona nada. Eu até tentei usá-lo para tentar entender onde quer chegar, mas ainda não estou entendendo. Explique melhor o problema.

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta tentando explicar melhor o problema.

Comment: Acho que sua resposta ta na sua pergunta ....Como fazer para que quando o dia de montagem for maior que o ultimo dia do mes.. `dataUltimaMontagem.Day.Equals(DateTime.Now.Day)`  porque não faz `dataUltimaMontagem.Day <=  DateTime.Now.Day`

Comment: @JonathanBarcela Se o `DiaMontagem` for **31/10** e o período `Mensal` a `UltimaMontagem` tem que ser quando? **30/11** ou **01/12**?

Comment: @jbueno Tem que ser igual ao ultimo dia do mês.

Comment: Eu modifiquei seu código do jeito certo. Agora ele executa e é possível ver o resultado. https://dotnetfiddle.net/49fWwE. Fiz uma modificação, é isto que deseja?

Comment: @bigown Esta solução não atende. Coloquei um item com DataUltimaMontagem com o dia 17/10/2015 e a data de montagem pro dia 17 e ele passou. Eu preciso validar o dia da montagem também, desconsiderando apenas nos casos citados na pergunta(meses 31 e fevereiro) quando o dia for maior que o ultimo dia do mês.

Comment: Cara, só você consegue entender isso que você tá falando.

Comment: Então ainda não deu para entender o problema. Você diz "DataMontagem + Periodicidade = 19/11/2015. Este item seria desconsiderado pois o resultado é maior que a DataAtual(18/11/2015).". Dia 17 não é maior, então passa mesmo. Se o problema não estiver bem definido, nenhuma solução vai te atender. Não é problema de código, é problema de regra. Você não sabe qual é a regra. Acho melhor fechar a pergunta, até você saber qual é ela.

Comment: @bigown Note que o método leva em consideração o dia. Isso faz parte da regra, que já está definida. Leve em consideração também a parte da pergunta onde diz: 

 "Como eu faço para que Itens com o Dia da Montagem maior do que o ultimo dia do mês sejam considerados e passem pelo filtro. "

Comment: @JonathanBarcela acho melhor você editar a pergunta e fazer uma lista das regras de uma maneira bem organiza, realmente está impossível de entender o que você precisa. Está muito confusa a pergunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você precisa saber qual o último dia do mês, como você disse, foi dado dia 31, mas o mês vai até dia 30 etc

Tem uma função em `DateTime` que é [**`DaysInMonth`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth(v=vs.110).aspx).

Você deve passar para esse método o ano e mês, que ele te indica se o mês vai até dia 31, 30, 28, 29

Exemplo

```
int ultimaDiaMes = DateTime.DaysInMonth(2015, 2); // irá retornar 28
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer um `ExtesionMethod` para seu `DateTime`, caso o problema com a data seja recorrente. Exemplo:

```cs
using System.IO;
using System;
using ExtensionMethods;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DateTime hoje = DateTime.Now;

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Hoje é {0}", hoje));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Último dia é {0}", hoje.LastDayOfThisMonth()));
    }
}

namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static DateTime LastDayOfThisMonth(this DateTime date)
        {
            return new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: **NÃO**. Use a *extension* nativa [DateTime.DaysInMonth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/system.datetime.daysinmonth(v=vs.95).aspx/css).